# How to copy a row of a table using spring jdbc

Tags: oracle, spring, jdbc

I need to copy a row except one column which is the unique key to another row using spring jdbc. I'm getting nullpointer exception even though I check for null values. Is ther any other good way to achieve this? Help me. Thanks. Please find my code below:

```
insert.update(new Object[] { 
                    argModel.getKey(),
                    CommonUtils.isNotNull(argModel.getPage_Key())?argModel.getPage_Key():"",
                    CommonUtils.isNotNull(argModel.getNoteBookRef())?argModel.getNoteBookRef():"", 
                    argModel.getBatchNum(),
                    alStructKey,
                    identifiedStructKey,
                    reactionKey,
                    argModel.getAnalysisType(),
                    CommonUtils.isNotNull(argModel.getSubmitted_Amt())?argModel.getSubmitted_Amt():"0",
                    CommonUtils.isNotNull(argModel.getEstimated_Purity())?argModel.getEstimated_Purity():"0",
                    CommonUtils.isNotNull(argModel.getKey_Nmr_Exp())?argModel.getKey_Nmr_Exp():"",
                    CommonUtils.isNotNull(argModel.getSolvent_Used())?argModel.getSolvent_Used():"",
                    CommonUtils.isNotNull(argModel.getProbe_Used())?argModel.getProbe_Used():"",
                    CommonUtils.isNotNull(argModel.getSamp_Temp())?argModel.getSamp_Temp():"0",
                    CommonUtils.isNotNull(argModel.getAchiral_Purity())?new Float(argModel.getAchiral_Purity()):0.0,
                    CommonUtils.isNotNull(argModel.getChiral_Purity())?new Float(argModel.getChiral_Purity()):0.0,
                    CommonUtils.isNotNull(argModel.getPeak1_Amt())?argModel.getPeak1_Amt():"0",
                    CommonUtils.isNotNull(argModel.getPeak2_Amt())?argModel.getPeak2_Amt():"0",
                    CommonUtils.isNotNull(argModel.getRequestId())?argModel.getRequestId():"0",
                    CommonUtils.isNotNull(argModel.getSubmissionComments())?argModel.getSubmissionComments():"",
                    CommonUtils.isNotNull(argModel.getStatusComments())?argModel.getStatusComments():"",
                    CommonUtils.isNotNull(argModel.getCcList())?argModel.getCcList():"",
                    argModel.isSaveSampleForPickUp()?"YES":"NO",
                    CommonUtils.isNotNull(argModel.getAnalyticalContact())?argModel.getAnalyticalContact():"",
                    argModel.getSubmittedOn(),
                    argModel.getAcceptedOn(),
                    CommonUtils.isNotNull(argModel.getSubmissionStatus())?argModel.getSubmissionStatus():"",
                    CommonUtils.isNotNull(argModel.getSubmitter())?argModel.getSubmitter():"",
                    CommonUtils.isNotNull(argModel.getTherapetuicArea())?argModel.getTherapetuicArea():"",
                    CommonUtils.isNotNull(argModel.getProjectCode())?argModel.getProjectCode():"",
                    CommonUtils.isNotNull(argModel.getCro())?argModel.getCro():"",
                    CommonUtils.isNotNull(argModel.getSiteCode())?argModel.getSiteCode():"",
                    CommonUtils.isNotNull(argModel.getAnalysisXml())?StorageUtils.toClobObject(CommonUtils.replaceSpecialCharsinXML(argModel.getAnalysisXml())):""
                    });
```

Comment: insert into submitted_batch 
select * from submitted_batch where analytical_page_key='24695d63ac1e31a8730de255639e5b2c8f7972d8'

Comment: I can use the above query. But it will fail as it has unique constraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
insert into submitted_batch select (your_new_page_key, n1, n2, n3, ...) from submitted_batch where analytical_page_key='24695d63ac1e31a8730de255639e5b2c8f7972d8';
```

where your_new_page_key is your new key, and n1, n2, n3, ... are all the non-primary key columns.

Comment: Thanks. But I'm getting the following error while executing.. ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Comment: Not a problem.  Happy to help!